# case compare on MySQL does not match

Tags: mysql, sql, select, compare, case

I try to compare the variable @ecart who was a result of a subqueries.

I tryed to convert my variable in DECIMAL, but that change nothing.

```
SET @ecart := 0;
SELECT CASE @ecart := (TIME_TO_SEC(t.temps) - TIME_TO_SEC((
                        SELECT MIN(t.temps) as Temps
                        FROM temps t
                        INNER JOIN inscription i ON t.ide_inscription = i.id AND i.ide_calendrier = 3
                        INNER JOIN type_temps tt ON tt.id = t.ide_type_temps AND tt.intitule = 'Temps Final')))
    WHEN @ecart = 0 THEN ""
    WHEN @ecart<60 THEN CONCAT('+',@ecart)
    WHEN @ecart BETWEEN 60 AND 3600 THEN CONCAT('+',SEC_TO_TIME(@ecart))
    ELSE CONCAT('++',@ecart)
    END as Ecart
FROM dag_evenement.temps t
INNER JOIN dag_evenement.inscription i ON t.ide_inscription = i.id AND i.ide_calendrier = 3
INNER JOIN dag_evenement.type_temps tt ON tt.id = t.ide_type_temps AND tt.intitule = 'Temps Final'
INNER JOIN dag_ticketing2.personne p ON i.ide_personne = p.IDPersonne
ORDER BY t.temps ASC;
```

and the result was

```
+0
++15
++58
++125
++141
++157
++209
++226
++240
++271
++283
++288
++290
++296
++298
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: I want to show if @ecart = 0 to didnt show the substract, 
if ecart < 60 to show ecart
if ecart >= 60 and ecart < 3600 to show the minutes:seconds
else to show the time with the format H:i:s
But when i tr to test only the first one and the else match not the second and the third